# STM32L0: Pause Timer?

Tags: stm32

I'm using a Nucleo STM32L031. In my application, I want to generate interrupts using Timer and a Compare Value.
My problem is: I want to start the timer, then pause it (so the counter value is halt, but not be reset), then start the timer again (from the halt value). And then when it reaches the compared value, it generates an interrupt.

How can I pause the timer without reseting the counter value ?
And also I'm not sure whether: *HAL_TIM_BASE_Stop_IT()* function will pause or reset the counter value?

Thanks.
Bien

Answer (score 3):

There two ways as minimum:

**first** is set/reset CEN bit in CR1 register, when timer paused this way it can be reconfigured and use (but I can't say this about reconfigure through HAL functions)

```
htimX.Instance->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN; // pause tim
htimX.Instance->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;  // resume tim
```

**second** is gate/ungate tim clock, when timer paused this way it does not clocked, so it cannot be reconfigured, but exist one advance is power saving

```
__HAL_RCC_TIMx_CLK_ENABLE();  // pause tim
__HAL_RCC_TIMx_CLK_DISABLE(); // resume tim
```

Comment: Worth noting that with the clock gated via the RCC, you will not be able to access any of the timer registers (including the count). I can't remember if it's reset or gated clock, or a combination of both, but it may cause a bus fault if you are accessing a clock gated peripheral's registers.

Comment: thanks for your help @imbearr.
    - 1st approach: I think it is possible to select the wanted timer.
    - 2nd approach: when using these HAL function, does it stop the clock for all the timers ? or can we select only the wanted timer ?

Comment: I did work with `STM32F207`, `F091`, `F411`; `STM8L051`, `L151` and for all of these MCUs `RCC` registers have one bit clocks control for each of peripheral instance. So I think only wanted timer clock will be affected. Anyway you can open reference manual for your MCU and see what bits presents in RCC_APxxENR registers or just open definition of `__HAL_RCC_TIMx_CLK_ENABLE()` macros.